# Filtration of a set Really dont get it

Tags: filtrations

Let $a\in \mathbb R$. Consider the filtrations $\varphi,\varphi':\mathbb N\to {\rm Sub}(\mathbb R)$ defined by $\varphi(n)=\left(a-\frac{1}{n},a+\frac{1}{n}\right)$ and $\varphi'(n)=\left[a-\frac{1}{n},a+\frac{1}{n} \right]$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$ show that $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ is eventually constant with respect to $\varphi$ if and only if it is eventually constant with respect to $\varphi'$. Moreover show that $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ is eventually bounded with respect to $\varphi$ if and only if it is eventually bounded with respect to $\varphi'$.

Comment: What have you tried? What don't you get?

Comment: I literally dont understand I know what a filtration is but bounded with respect to phi or his two filtration sets have me clueless.

Comment: Your entire "question" (I don't see any question marks) seems to be a quotation from a book. **What are you quoting from?** Unattributed quotations are not allowed here. Intellectual property laws, you know.

Comment: The text you're using must have definitions of "constant/eventually bounded wrt $\varphi.$ Have you tried the index, or can you hunt for these definitions, and could you add them to your question?

Comment: Bof it’s a hw problem for a class with no text book sorry if it seems like it’s from a book I wouldn’t know. And as for defining phi no clue I thought phi just meant this is a filtration.